# MKMapAnnotationView subview animation not working on iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mkannotationview

I have an `MKMapPinAnnotationView` subclass that should display an animation that looks more or less exactly like the pulsating animation that you see when enabling the `showsUserLocation` option on the `MKMapView`. The animation works like a charm on iOS 6, but shows nothing on iOS 5.1. After some investigation, I found out that on iOS 5 adding a subview to the `MKAnnotationView` does nothing, unless you explicitly call `setNeedsDisplay` afterward. Is there some method I need to override on iOS 5 to make it work, or is there anything else that I'm missing?

Comment: It would help if you posted the code you currently have.